# Lunar maria, always on the side facing the planet?

Tags: hard-science, moons

Suppose we have an Earthlike planet, with a rocky moon orbiting it. Under what conditions would dark lunar maria form on its surface, and would they always be on the side facing the planet? For Earth’s Moon, it appears that the maria face the Earth due to heat radiating from the molten Earth. How universal is this phenomenon? Does it depend on, for example:

- Whether the moon was formed in an impact, or if it was captured?
- The size of the moon, from the smallest rocky body that forms a sphere under its own gravity, to being the equal to the size of the planet (a double planet)?
- The presence of gas giants in the solar system? (It seems Earth’s Moon got its maria from asteroid bombardments caused by Jupiter and Saturn.)

Comment: There is no scientific consensus regarding the reasons for the peculiar distribution of Lunar seas. From the Wikipedia article on [Lunar maria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_mare): *"the reason that the* mare *basalts are predominantly located on the near-side hemisphere of the Moon is still being debated by the scientific community"*. The same article list a series of common misconceptions about Lunar seas.

Comment: This is more a question for Astronomy SE that Worldbuilding.  There's no worldbuilding here.

Comment: "For Earth’s Moon, it appears that the maria face the Earth due to heat radiating from the molten Earth." As was pointed out earlier, this is nonsense. The maria and craters we see now came *much* later than Earth and the Moon solidified. Also Maria don't stem from bombardment. They're volcanic in origin.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape Explaining that, with references, would likely be the correct answer, then.

Comment: @kingledion: That's also on the wiki page AlexP linked.

Comment: personally I think the maria are more dense, so even if they formed on the far side of the moon, the moons center of gravity would be just slightly off center, and it would tend roll down hill as it were toward the pull of earths gravity, but that is just my theory... lol

Answer (score 2):

We see the maria of the Moon because the moon is tidally locked with the Earth.  It is a theory that the near side and far side appear so different because the far side has taken so many more hits from space debris than the more sheltered nearside.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *blueworld*! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!